# Blur images with Shrine and image_processing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, shrine

I am trying to blur images in my Ruby on Rails application, using the Shrine gem. This is my uploader file:

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

class ImageUploader < Shrine
  Attacher.derivatives_processor do |original|
    magick = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)
    {
      blurred: magick.append('-blur 0x8').resize_to_limit!(1024, 1024)
    }
  end
end
```

I set up my model, controller and form in the most basic way, the same as in the Shrine Getting Started tutorial - https://shrinerb.com/docs/getting-started.
When I try to save an image I get following error:

> *** MiniMagick::Error Exception: `convert /tmp/shrine20191112-4479-1xo3vgk.jpg -auto-orient -blur 0x5 -resize 1024x1024> -sharpen 0x1 /tmp/image_processing20191112-4479-1w094sa.jpg` failed with error:
>   convert: unrecognized option `-blur 0x5' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/893.
>   "

Without the `append('-blur 0x8')` it works just fine, what am I doing wrong? My ImageMagick version is **7.0.7-11**.

Btw I wouldn't mind blurring the image with libvips, I just have more experience with ImageMagick so that's what I went with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify each command-line argument separately, in this case `-blur` and `0x8`:

```
magick.append('-blur', '0x8').resize_to_limit!(1024, 1024)
```

You can also call the `#blur` method, which will get applied as `-blur` through the magic of `method_missing`:

```
magick.blur('0x8').resize_to_limit!(1024, 1024)
```

Comment: Janko, Is-it possible to blur only an area on the image ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the libvips equivalent would be:

```rb
require "image_processing/vips"

class ImageUploader < Shrine
  Attacher.derivatives_processor do |original|
    vips = ImageProcessing::Vips.source(original)
    {
      blurred: vips.resize_to_limit(1024, 1024).gaussblur(2).call
    }
  end
end
```

Since [unknown methods are simply delegated to ruby-vips](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/master/doc/vips.md#method_missing).

If you can, put the resize first, it's a lot quicker. You'll get more consistent results too, since the degree of blur won't depend on how large the resize is.